# bugs to check for site on different browsers and devices

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

Is there any tool or site where I can check any site bugs.
that how any particular site is running on different browsers and different devices?
any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...*"

Answer (score 1):

https://browsershots.org/

If you want to see how pages render in various browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides free virtual machines loaded with various versions of IE.

[Modern.IE](http://www.modern.ie/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.browserstack.com/ allows you to interact with the website as well, or just render images.

There is no plan for that, but I was creating screenshots of my (public) website for free.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

**13 Essential Tools to Check Cross-Browser Compatibility**

http://mashable.com/2014/02/26/browser-testing-tools/